# construct sub level list in xml by using xslt

Tags: xml, xslt, sublist

create XML structure by level using xslt.

input file:

```
<list type="bulleted"></list>
<list2 type="bulleted"></list2>
<list3 type="bulleted"></list3>
<list3 type="bulleted"></list3>
<list2 type="bulleted"></list2>
<list3 type="bulleted"></list3>
<list4 type="bulleted"></list4>
<list2 type="bulleted"></list2>
```

result will be,

```
<list type="bulleted"><list2 type="bulleted"><list3 type="bulleted"></list3> <list3 type="bulleted"></list3></list2> <list2 type="bulleted"><list3 type="bulleted"><list4 type="bulleted"></list4></list3></list2><list2 type="bulleted"></list2></list>
```

Comment: Hi welcome to SO, please revise the question showing what you have tried.

Comment: i need to move the list under the level by level using xsl

Comment: Please explain in more detail the logic of the required transformation. Is the nesting based on the names of the elements? Are these really the names of the elements? Why is there no `list1`?  -- Note also that the input is not an XML document, since it has no single root element.

Comment: My requirement is to create a list and sublist to the depth of 5 levels in XML using XSLT. The input XML has them in sequential order, i.e., they are not nested. Treat list as the parent list and list2, list3, and list4 as sublists.

Comment: You haven't really answered my questions. Is the level determined by the element name and are those the real names? The problem with your scheme is that that the logic by which `list3` could determine that its parent is `list2` by subtracting 1 does not apply to `list2`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To minimize the example to what's the only real problem here, I have modified your input to:

**XML**

```
<root>
    <list1 id="1"></list1>
    <list2 id="2"></list2>
    <list3 id="3"></list3>
    <list3 id="4"></list3>
    <list2 id="5"></list2>
    <list3 id="6"></list3>
    <list4 id="7"></list4>
    <list2 id="8"></list2>
</root>
```

*Note: the added `id` numbers play no role in the transformation; their only purpose is to enable easy comparison of output to input.*

The rule for nesting is that each list is nested under the first preceding sibling whose list number is 1 less that its own.

It is assumed that there is only one top list, and that its name is `list1`.

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:key name="list-by-parent" 
         match="*[starts-with(name(), 'list')]" 
         use="generate-id(preceding-sibling::*[name()=concat('list', substring-after(name(current()),'list') - 1)][1])"/>

<xsl:template match="/root">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="list1"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*[starts-with(name(), 'list')]">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="key('list-by-parent', generate-id())"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<list1 id="1">
   <list2 id="2">
      <list3 id="3"/>
      <list3 id="4"/>
   </list2>
   <list2 id="5">
      <list3 id="6">
         <list4 id="7"/>
      </list3>
   </list2>
   <list2 id="8"/>
</list1>
```